# How to change the generic type of a field in a subclass?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a class, `A`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class A {

    protected List<Object> objects;

    public A() {
        objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    public A(List<Object> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public List<Object> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void addObject(Object o) {
        getObjects().add(o);
    }

}
```

I want to subclass it with a class called `B`, but changing the `objects` field to a `List<Number>`:

```
import java.util.List;

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public List<Number> getObjects() {
        return (List<Number>) super.getObjects();
    }

    @Override
    public void addObject(Object o) {
        getObjects().add((Number) o);
    }
}
```

This, however, throws a compiler error. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Introduce a type parameter to your A class...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class A<T> {

    protected List<T> objects;

    public A() {
        objects = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public A(List<T> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public List<T> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void addObject(T o) {
        getObjects().add(o);
    }

}
```

Now B doesn't actually need to override the methods...

```
public class B extends A<Number> {

}
```

Comment: I don't want users of `A` to be able to change the type. But I believe I have found a solution related to this.

Comment: @FireCubez Then you are broken. Beyond that, your whole approach looks *weird*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a key subtlety of how generics work in Java. If a type `T` extends a type `U`, we would expect that `List<T>` extends `List<U>`. But that's not the case. So when you try to return `List<Number>` as a subtype of `List<Object>` the compiler complains.

Note- the complaint isn't about the casting you do inside the function body, which is in itself dangerous. It's about the return type of the function which claims to be an override. In fancy terms, the return type is not "covariant" with the method in the superclass: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Covariant-return-types-in-Java.

So that explains the "why" behind the compiler error.

As for the "how" to do this correctly. Without seeing the use case, I must say [Bret C's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596650/5134722) is the way I would do it.